# Class 'Craft\ErrorHandler' not found in YiiBase.php after new Thread-Safe PHP install

Tags: php, yiic, cli

I've just upgraded PHP 7.0 on a standard Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS distro from non-thread safe to thread safe (using Michel Phillipe Luca's instructions here: http://php.net/manual/de/pthreads.installation.php).

I had a CLI method set up which was working perfectly fine, but after installing the thread-safe version of PHP (with no changes to the code), when I try to run `./craft/app/etc/console/yiic plugin method` I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Craft\ErrorHandler' not found in /var/www/asmar/subdomains/site/craft/app/framework/YiiBase.php:213
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/asmar/subdomains/site/craft/app/framework/base/CModule.php(393): YiiBase::createComponent(Array)
#1 /var/www/asmar/subdomains/site/craft/app/etc/console/ConsoleApp.php(220): CModule->getComponent('errorHandler', true)
#2 /var/www/asmar/subdomains/site/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(468): Craft\ConsoleApp->getComponent('errorHandler')
#3 /var/www/asmar/subdomains/site/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(749): CApplication->getErrorHandler()
#4 [internal function]: CApplication->handleException(Object(Error))
#5 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/asmar/subdomains/site/craft/app/framework/YiiBase.php on line 213
```

Any ideas how I may squash this?

Comment: Attempting to fully remove PHP & reinstall from scratch... I'm suspecting I have out of date packages or configs that are interfering with namespacing. Will update on results. Thanks for looking anyways!

Comment: This didn't seem to work..

Comment: I have the same problem. @Jonny Asmar did you ever solved this?

Comment: Also looking for an answer to this.

Comment: Sorry guys -- I have yet to find a solution to this :(